# CSS a:hover not working as hoped

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, mouseover

I'm trying to build my first site and am trying to use the "a:hover" feature in CSS but can't get it to work - the links look the same whether hovering or not.

Here's a snippet of my CSS file:

```
    /* main page elements */
    a:link
    {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:white;
    }

    a:visited
    {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:FFFFFF;
    }

    a:hover
    {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:blue;  
    }


    a:active
    {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:blue;
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Robert.

Comment: what is it doing wrong? Where is your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you need to change the color in `hover` state

Try something like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nhd2/)

eg.

```
HTML   

<a href ='#'> Hover Me </a>

css   

 a
 { 
     text-decoration: none; 
     color:#000000;
 }
 a:hover
 {
     color:#3399FF;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to finnish the text-decoration instruction :P

```
text-decoration: none;
```

or

```
text-decoration: underline;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually had it like this but removed it just before posting here. I've put it back - still doesn't work.


a:link
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}

a:visited
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:FFFFFF;
}

a:hover
{
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:blue;  
}


a:active
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:blue;
}

Comment: Sorry - I've amended the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Your might be transitioning from a:active to a:hover, which has the same color. Therefore you see no difference. Try setting a unique color for a:hover, and see what happens.

It would also help if you make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the `text-decoration:` parts, if you remove them or use a valid syntax your CSS should work.